Pattern rules in makefiles not matched
I have this simple makefile in makefiles/test.mk:
OUT_FLD = out

target: $(OUT_FLD)/target/.wit_target

$(OUT_FLD)/%/.wit_%:
    echo "Creating target: $*"
    touch $@

.PHONY: target

but make does not do anything when asked to build target.
When I run:
make --debug=v -f makefiles/test.mk target

I get:
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile 'makefiles/test.mk'...
Updating makefiles....
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file 'target'.
 File 'target' does not exist.
  Considering target file 'out/target/.wit_target'.
   File 'out/target/.wit_target' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'out/target/.wit_target'.
  Must remake target 'out/target/.wit_target'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'out/target/.wit_target', needed by 'target'.  Stop.

The target out/target/.wit_target should be matched by the rule $(OUT_FLD)/%/.wit_%, but it does not.
From this:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html
it should match as:

A target pattern is composed of a ‘%’ between a prefix and a suffix,
either or both of which may be empty.

Is there anyone who can help me?

The problem occurs also with this makefile (no $(OUT_FLD) ):
target: out/target/.wit_target

out/%/.wit_%:
    echo "Creating target: $*"
    touch $@

.PHONY: target


This makefile works as expected (obviously):
.PHONY: target

OUT_FLD = out

target: out/target/.wit_target

$(OUT_FLD)/target/.wit_target:
    echo "Creating target: $*"
    touch $@

it gives an error (the directory /out/target does not exist), but at least the rule is evaluated.

It seems that % can occur once. Am I right?

This question is similar to: Gnu make with multiple % in pattern rule?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Per the docs: "A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them)" (emphasis added).  The '%' can appear as many times as you like in the prerequisite list, but the target must have exactly one (else it is an ordinary rule, not a pattern rule).
